# Could Not Load Assembly MICROSOFT.SQLSERVER.BATCHPARSER on 32-BIT environment

Tags: sql-server, powershell, 32bit-64bit

I'm posting my problem here, hoping someone may help me to figure the issue.

So, for one of my clients I've developed a PS script that retrieve a table for a database and export it as a CSV directly to a Blob Storage. My script works fine in a 64-Bit environment. However, I cannot run it in a 32-Bit environment. I need to run it in a 32-Bit environment because the scheduler used by the client is a 32-Bit tool.
On my side, I've tried every thing I've already found around the net on this subject with no luck.

My problem as I said above is that I fail to run my script on a 32-Bit environment. I'm putting a screenshot of booth environment so you can see what I'm having.

The Green square is the expected result. The Yellow one is the error I'm having.
The Blue squares shows booth SqlServer Modules I downloaded (x86 & 64).

I have the same behavior from a CMD SHELL.

So My questions are:
Is there anyway to make this script working on a 32-Bit environment?
Else Is there anyway to force a 32-BIT CMD SHELL to open a 64-Bit session on PowerShell ?

Here is the FUll PS SCript :

```
param (
    [String]$SourceServer="" ,
    [String]$SourceDatabase="" ,


    [String]$DestinationStorageAccountName = "",
    [String]$DestinationStorageAccountContainrerName= "",

    [String]$DBUser = "",
    [String]$DBUserPWD = ""
)

FUNCTION Write-ToBlobStorage{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ResultString,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$DestinationStorageAccountName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$DestinationStorageAccountContainrerName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$FileName
    )

    write-host "Clear existing identies to keep cache fresh"
    Clear-AzContext -force

    write-host "Authenticate using the Managed identity"
    $account = Connect-AzAccount -identity
    if(-not $account.Context.Subscription.Id)
    {
        write-error "Failed to authenticate with the Managed identity. Ensure VM has a Managed identity enabled and is assigned the correct IAM roles"
        return
    }

    write-host "Get storage context"
    $context = New-AZStorageContext  -StorageAccountName $DestinationStorageAccountName

    write-host "Get storage Container"
    $container=Get-AzStorageContainer -Name $DestinationStorageAccountContainrerName -Context $context

    write-host "Writing Result to storage"
    $content = [system.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($ResultString)

    $container.CloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("$FileName.csv").UploadFromByteArray($content,0,$content.Length)

}


#Import-Module 'Az.KeyVault' -Force
#Import-Module -Name 'C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer' -Force
Import-Module -Name 'C:\Program Files (x86)\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SqlServer' -Force


$TLS12Protocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType] 'Ssl3 , Tls12'
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = $TLS12Protocol


$Query = "SELECT @@SERVERNAME"

$Result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SourceServer -Database $SourceDatabase -Query $Query | ConvertTo-Csv -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation

$ResultString = $Result -join "`r`n" 

Write-ToBlobStorage -ResultString $ResultString -DestinationStorageAccountName $DestinationStorageAccountName -DestinationStorageAccountContainrerName $DestinationStorageAccountContainrerName -FileName "TMP_Flux"

write-host "--- ALL DONE---"
```

And Here is The error for the 32-Bit :

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Could not load file or assembly 
'Microsoft.SqlServer.BatchParser, Version=15.100.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot 
find the file specified.
At C:\temp\ExportToBlobScript\ExportToBlob.ps1:87 char:11
+ $Result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $SourceServer -Database $Sour ...
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], FileNotFoundEx 
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.FileNotFoundException,Microsoft.SqlServ 
   er.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
 
Write-ToBlobStorage : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'ResultString' because 
it is an empty string.
At C:\temp\ExportToBlobScript\ExportToBlob.ps1:91 char:35
+ Write-ToBlobStorage -ResultString $ResultString -DestinationStorageAc ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Write-ToBlobStorage], Parameter 
   BindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAll 
   owed,Write-ToBlobStorage
 
--- ALL DONE---
```

And Here is the result for the 64-Bit:

```
Clear existing identies to keep cache fresh
Authenticate using the Managed identity
Get storage context
Get storage Container
Writing Result to storage
--- ALL DONE---
```

Many Thanks for all of you suggestions.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Larnu should I redo the post ??

Comment: If by "redo" you mean [edit] it to replace the image with the actual text, then yes. See the linked FAQ.

Comment: @Larnu Is it ok Now ??

Comment: Yes. Though I would suggest removing the images of code and errors; as otherwise someone might open the question, see the image (of code/error) and simply close the browser window/tab with the question. Images of code are a big deterrent for getting an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure.  But since you're only using Invoke-SqlCmd to run a query, you can eliminate the dependence on the SqlServer powershell module by using ADO.NET directly from PowerShell.  The SQL Server client libraries are part of the .NET framework, so they will be available on any Windows box.  So something like:

```
function Invoke-SqlCmd-Custom{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$ServerInstance,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$Database,
        [Parameter(Mandatory)][String]$Query 
    )

    $con = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    $con.ConnectionString = "Server=$ServerInstance;Database=$Database;Integrated Security=true"
    try
    {
        $con.Open()
        $cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
        $cmd.CommandText = $Query 
        $dt = new-object System.Data.DataTable
        $rdr = $cmd.ExecuteReader()
        $dt.Load($rdr)
        return $dt.Rows
    }
    finally
    {
      $con.Close()
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne , Thanks for the custom function I'll give it a try. However, I would like to understand the issue with the SqlServer module. Is it not compatible with 32-Bit or something like that ??